# How to read from a file that is on github (with python)?

Tags: python, file, numpy, github, request

I need to read from here, for example: https://github.com/Kevinjareczek/CSCI490/blob/master/traininglabels.txt preferably into a numpy array in order to be able to work with the data. I just want the single numbers to be stored in an array so I can work with them. I've tried several times but keep also getting \n characters and such. Here's what I'm trying right now, but I'm just getting blank characters:

```
filename =  "https://github.com/Kevinjareczek/CSCI490/blob/master/traininglabels.txt"
r = np.array
r = requests.get(filename)
arr = np.array([c for c in r.text])
print(arr[5])
```

I also need to do this into a two dimensional numpy array, but with characters (from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kevinjareczek/CSCI490/master/trainingimages). I'm quite literally brand new to python and was just thrown into this for my computer vision class, so any help would be appreciated. I understand for the most part how numpy arrays/slicing/operations work, but I'm not quite sure how to get this data that I need.

Comment: For debugging in python, it is common to use lots of print statements. I do that myself a lot to make sure my variables contain what I think they should contain. For this task, you might try to first convert `r.text` into a python list using [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and then converting the list to a numpy array. You may also have to use [numpy.reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to get the 2D array you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
filename = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kevinjareczek/CSCI490/master/traininglabels.txt"
r = requests.get(filename)
arr = np.array([c.strip() for c in r.text.splitlines()])
print(arr[5])
```

`.strip()` will remove any whitespace characters -- both spaces and things like tabs and newlines. In this case just spaces since we're already using `.splitlines()`.